# Cant create a a exe file using cxfreeze, KeyError: 'IMPORT_STAR'

Tags: python

I wrote a code to rename files removing special letters and other punctuation marks, i did the tests in my own PC and i managed to rename over 140 files with the code with no problem, but when i tried to use the code to try to rename the files on my Company's Network, the code starts to work on the initial files and manages to run on about 90 0f the 140 files, but then the code stops. Is there any explanation to why this happens?

tried runniing the code on the same files but in my PC instead of the Network and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze and dependencies (cx_Logging, Lief) are not declared compatible with Python 3.12 (yet!) and do not provide a wheels for it.

But, you can test the latest development build:

`pip install --upgrade --pre --extra-index-url https://marcelotduarte.github.io/packages/ cx_Freeze`

For conda-forge the command is:

`conda install -y --no-channel-priority -S -c https://marcelotduarte.github.io/packages/conda cx_Freeze`

**Reference**:

[#issue_2117](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/2117):
By Owner: [marcelotduarte](https://github.com/marcelotduarte) commented on Oct 30, 2023